# Android to .NET - XML-RPC or KSoap?

Tags: .net, android, soap, xml-rpc, ksoap2

We are designing an internal system that will have a .NET PC base station and many Android mobiles, communicating over WiFi. Can't decide between SOAP or XML-RPC protocol. Primary concerns are maturity, compatibility, and the minimizing of coding/integration, in that order. Which is best?

Ben

Answer (score 0):

is REST an option?  That seems to be the simplest form of Web Services now a days.  Look into WCF 3.5

Comment: Thanks, we thought about that, but decided for our system that a procedure call type method would be simpler. But, if anyone has a comment on the maturity and compatibility of REST on Android (which I believe is built-in?) that would be useful too.